# Большие массивы данных и MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb, django

Добрый день, у меня такой вопрос: есть определенные файлы (по сути растровые изображения? которые можно представить в виде двумерных массивов), растры-массивы чисел с плавающей точкой размером примерно 6000 на 6000. Нужно иногда чтобы веб-приложение делало некоторые операции с этими данными (сложение, умножение и прочее), например сложить один массив с другим и потом умножить на третий. Веб-приложение базируется на Django\Python.

Так вот сам вопрос: насколько целесообразно записывать сначала эти массивы, например в MongoDB? насколько MongoDB вообще хороша для таких задач (может есть что-то более подходящее)?

Заранее большое спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для простых численных операций над 2D-массивами, можно использовать `numpy` -- быстр и удобен и установщики доступны на всех популярных системах.

Простой и переносимый вариант -- использовать родной для numpy-массив npy-формат, если нужно сохранить массивы на диск.

MongoDB не очень подходит для хранения таких данных. Если нужно, то можно легко [сериализовать numpy массив и запихнуть получившийся блоб в MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6376382/4279):

```
buf = io.BytesIO()
numpy.save(buf, numpy_array)
record['image'] = pymongo.binary.Binary(buf.getvalue())
```

Если есть потребность хранить много-терабайтные численные данные, то можно попробовать [hdf5 файловый формат](http://www.h5py.org/).

Comment: Насколько мне известно(я пока в этой области не очень хорошо разбираюсь) в Mongo можно как в именно в поле сохранить файл(данные), так и например в GridFS, насколько я сейчас понимаю gridfs именно для хранения файлов и предназначен, я правильно понимаю?

Comment: @Rumato: мотивация для GridFS -- хранить данные, размер которых превышает предел для Mongo документа (например, больше чем `1<<24` байт). То есть случай, когда Mongo ещё меньше подходит для хранения.

Чтобы оперативно отображать в JS клиенте, можно попробовать в jpeg дублировать массивы для хранения или хранить картинки по квадрантам, чтобы контролировать размер.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, буду разбираться.

Answer (score 1):

Может посмотришь в сторону CUDA (PyCUDA или другие  библеотеки работающие с этой технологией)

Comment: дело же не как считать, дело как хранить и потом быстро извлекать -- отображать в JS клиенте